# Error: Google Apps Script: Exception: You do not have permission to perform that action

Tags: google-cloud-platform, g-suite

I am an add-ons developer and when I hosted my add-on on google workspace marketplace, it let's user install my add-on(google sheet add-on) for the first time. When user tries to access the same add-on in another spreadsheet, he/she receives this error in the console of the chrome tab.

`Google Apps Script: Exception: You do not have permission to perform that action.`

I tried to reauthorize the add-on and re-auth happened but the issue still remains.

Note: If a user tries to open the add-on in the sheet where he/she installed it, they are able to access it without any problem, but it doesn't open in any new spreadsheet.

Any advice would be very much appreciated.